# Adobe LiveCycle save button

Tags: button, save, livecycle-designer

I have a button with the Control Type Regular and this Javascript attached to it:

```
this.saveAs("/C/temp/temp.pdf");
```

Now it should svae the file but nothing happens.

I have no idea what it could be.
I have no experience with Adobe LiveCycle

Answer (score 0):

Submit button is confusing. Usually each submit button has three type of control execute, regular and submit. It depends what you want to do.

Advantage of regular button is you do have click event but execute and submit doesn't. --- This line might be confusion if you don't know what events are.

Events are basically action, like click event mean --blaah blaah action should happen when that button is clicked. Initialize event mean set in the beginning some action.

What I am thinking is you may not have place you code in a right event. Make sure its in click event.